# Error: cannot bind ‘std::basic_ostream<char>’ lvalue to ‘std::basic_ostream<char>&&’ on generic value

Tags: c++, c++11, templates, stringstream

I'm trying to check if a value is correct via a function template. The values that I check are all booleans or integers. If the values match, the function will return boost::none, otherwise it will return a string indicating the mismatch.

For some reason the compiler won't accept my solution and returns the error: `cannot bind ‘std::basic_ostream<char>’ lvalue to ‘std::basic_ostream<char>&&’`

But the values that go into the sstream are all bools and ints... which a stringstream should be able to take, right?

This is the code:

```cpp
template<class Model>
class AbstractReference {
protected:
    template<typename T>
    boost::optional<std::string> checkValue(const boost::optional<T>& expected, const T& found, std::string valueName) {
        if(!expected)
            return boost::none;
        if(expected.get() == found)
            return boost::none;
        std::stringstream ss;
        ss << "{ valueName: '" << valueName << "', ";
        ss << "expected :'" << expected.get() << "', "; // this is where I get the error
        ss << "found: '" << found << "' }";
        return ss.str();
    }

    template<typename T>
    inline std::vector<std::string> checkReference(const AbstractReference<T>& expected, const T& found, const std::string& blockName) {
        // Impl not needed for example
    }
public:
    virtual std::vector<std::string> getMismatchStrings(const Model& model) = 0;
};

class CrossoverFilterReference final : public AbstractReference<datamodel::CrossoverFilter> {
    boost::optional<constants::CrossoverFilterAlignment> align;
    boost::optional<bool> enabled;
    // other variables and functions
public:
    
    boost::optional<constants::CrossoverFilterAlignment> getAlign() const;
    void setAlign(constants::CrossoverFilterAlignment align);
    boost::optional<bool> isEnabled() const;
    void setEnabled(bool enabled);
    // other functions
    
    std::vector<std::string> getMismatchStrings(const datamodel::CrossoverFilter& model) override {
        std::vector<std::string> result;
        auto alignCheck = checkValue(align, model.getAlign(), "align");
        if(alignCheck)
            result.push_back(alignCheck.get());
        auto enabledCheck = checkValue(enabled, model.isEnabled(), "enabled");
        if(enabledCheck)
            result.push_back(enabledCheck.get());

//other checks
    
        return result;
    }
};

// Actual class looks a lot different
class CrossoverFilter final {
    int align;
    bool enabled;
    
public:
    CrossoverFilter(std::shared_ptr<types::CrossoverFilterData> data);
    
    int getAlign() const;
    bool isEnabled() const;
};
```

Comment: Whats is the type of `T` in this invocation?

Comment: please show a [mre] and the full error message. Works for me: https://godbolt.org/z/qWMTb9osh

Comment: @MikeVine T is a value like a bool or an int

Comment: @AlanBirtles While making the example, I found out that I'm using an enum somewhere. It has an underlying type that I want to print, but yeah... That was the problem

Comment: still not a [mre]

Comment: the first step of fixing an error is reading the complete error message. It tells you the exact location of the error, it repeats the expression that has the error and usually more valuable information. This is what happens when I try this with the code you posted: https://godbolt.org/z/dWdsEcEzx.